# Props not passed down to children using React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following this [tutorial on React-Redux](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/) and I stumbled upon error on 1st part of section "React Redux tutorial: asynchronous actions in Redux, the naive way".

```
    Post.componentDidMount
    src/js/components/Posts.js:12
       9 | 
      10 | componentDidMount() {
      11 |   // calling the new action creator
    > 12 |   this.props.getData();
         | ^  13 | }
      14 | 
      15 | render() {
```

My understanding is that props from store is not passed down from the **App** component to **Posts** component. I have repeated the steps several times but I still cannot see the exact culprit. The source code from Git works just fine. I noticed, there are difference between my local and that of the GIT repo.

This is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "react-redux-study",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5"
      }
    }
```

And this is the [package.json](https://github.com/valentinogagliardi/react-redux-tutorial/blob/async-action-thunk/package.json) from the Git repo.

UPDATE: Added my App.js and Posts.js
App.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import List from "./List";
    import Form from "./Form";
    import { Post } from "./Posts";

    const App = () => (
      <>
        <div>
          <h2>Articles</h2>
          <List />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Add a new article</h2>
          <Form />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>API posts</h2>
          <Post />
        </div>
      </>
    );

    export default App;
```

Posts.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { getData } from "../actions/index";

    export class Post extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        // calling the new action creator
        this.props.getData();
      }

      render() {
        return null;
      }
    }

    export default connect(
      null,
      { getData }
    )(Post);
```

I can actually just move on and use the source code from Git but I do want to understand what is the exact issue.

Comment: Please post the relevant code of `app.js` and `posts.js`

Comment: Hello, I added the files. thanks

Comment: Did you check the redux dev tools? Is the action being called?

Comment: Also, while you are mapping the dispatch action methods, did you check if you are mapping your store to your children component's props?

Comment: Found  the issue :) I was importing { Post } instead of the default from Posts.js. Didn't notice that immediately. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue :**

```
// posts.js
export class Post extends Component { // <---- First : Export
   ...
}

export default connect( // <----- Second : Export 
  null,
  { getData }
)(Post);


// inside app.js
// you are importing first import, not the default which is connecting to you store
import { Post } from "./Posts";
```

**Solution :**

Change this line

```
import { Post } from "./Posts";
```

To

```
// import the default one
import Post from "./Posts";
```

Comment: @NothingBox,I think now that's another issue,in your code there is no use of data, no action reducer mentioned, you should post another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

In app component

```
<Post getData={postdata} />
```

In Posts component you can get data like this.

```
  componentDidMount() {
  let posts=this.props.getData;
}
```